# How to resolve the "unable to install update" error for OTA iOS updates?

Tags: ipad, ios, software-update

For some reason, I keep getting an error when I try to install an OTA update on my iPad. The update downloads without any issue, and I have over 1 GB of space free. I am currently facing the issue with the iOS 5.1.1 update. Screenshot of error below.

[image: iPad update error]

I faced this issue with the 5.1 update as well, and ended up using iTunes for the update. I have the 16 GB wifi model of the iPad 2. Restarting the iPad doesn't help either.

My 3rd gen iPod touch has no issues with the OTA updates. This seems to be a common problem, and people have faced it on different devices as well. No one seems to have found a foolproof solution so far on the net.

Is there any fix for this, as the iTunes route is a much heavier download.

Comment: Does this iPad happen to be jailbroken? OTA updates always fail on jailbroken devices (they need to be restored/updated via iTunes instead).

Comment: @britta Nope, not jailbroken.

Comment: FWIW, I finally managed to install an OTA update (6.0.1) after a spate of iTunes based updates. The only difference this time was that I was connected to a proper wifi point rather than tethered through my phone.

Comment: Updated via iTunes is a better way and here you can check https://www.easeus.com/iphone-recovery/the-latest-version-of-itunes.html

Answer (score -1):

if you download updates very soon after Apple releases them, they can sometimes get corrupted because the server is sending you the individual packages at the same time as it it send them to many other people. You may just need to wait a while and try again.

Comment: Weird idea of how servers work. Obviously wrong.